# Save data and view even after closing application and when opening it again don't load data and view again

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have a listview that get posts and data of users, I want to save my data and view even if I closed my application and re-opened it, I need it to open the same data that was loaded and the same view and don't load data and view again just like facebook does.
Can anybody help me?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your posts in Android Sqlite Database and then load data from sqlite then make a network request.

[Sqlite Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: one more good sqlite android tutorial to start http://www.quicktips.in/basic-android-sqlite-database-exampletutorial/

Comment: I think the OP means that he does not want to make a request to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you need to store the information on the actual phone.

[Use shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)